# Use database table as CSV dataset for JMeter

Tags: database, dataset, jmeter, performance-testing, credentials

I am currently doing performance testing with JMeter for an application in my company. The application requires a login and I have to use multiple users. The way this is usually done in JMeter seems to be via CSV dataset, however I have access to the database and can read all the credentials from there directly.

Since it is a test environment, all users have the same password, so I can hardcode it, but I need the list of usernames. JMeter can already do JDBC requests, but I was wondering if there was any way to use the results from such a request as a dataset.

The ideal way would be for me to query the database for the usernames and use those as input for the login test.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it is possible.

1. Follow the steps from [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) to establish JDBC Connection and execute your query.
2. Define a variable in the "Variable Name" input of the JDBC Request sampler

[image: Variable Name]
3. Query results will be available in form of

```
actor_1=John
actor_2=Doe
etc.
```

[image: Results]

If you need to deal with several columns, the approach is the same. See [official documentation on JDBC Request Sampler for example](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example, but this was not exactly what I was looking for. I managed to establish the database connection and can get the list of usernames, but I don't know how to use them like a CSV dataset. Each request in a thread group should pick one of the names to execute. That's where I got stuck.

Comment: Take a look at [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and [__evalVar](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar ) functions combination, you will be able to get unique user from the DB with somewhat like `${__evalVar(actor_${__threadNum})}` expression. See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) guide for advanced information on various JMeter functions.